# swing text editor that color and highlight

Tags: java, swing, text-editor

i am writing an application that the user need to writes a javascript script as an input, right now i have a simple JTextArea but i would like to change it with something that will do some highlights and code coloring to make the script more coherent.

do you know any open source thing that does that?

thanks

Answer (score 14):

[RSyntaxTextArea](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea)

> RSyntaxTextArea is a syntax highlighting text component for Java Swing. It extends JTextComponent so it integrates completely with the standard javax.swing.text package. It is fast and efficient, and can be used in any application that needs to edit or view source code.
>
> RSyntaxTextArea was originally part of the RText programmer's text editor, but is currently being made into a separate component, reusable in any Swing application.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/). It is mainly an editor written in Java and not an editor component. But perhaps you can extract the editor component from the jar file.

Just an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what the [NetBeans Platform](http://platform.netbeans.org/) provides. I know that they do release components as JARfiles, but they're not available in the Maven central repo, which has kept me from using any.

Answer (score 2):

Standard JEditorPane swing component will do it.

UPDATE: Check out the [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) and [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Comment: Out of the box, or do you have to create an `EditorKit`/`Document` that parses the text and provides the highlighting?

Comment: @kdgregory By default JEditorPane knows about html, rtf and plain text. But more kits/documents can be configured

Answer (score 2):

I guess, as far as i guessed, you need something other than JTextArea, so you can show different things in different colours. Well that can be done by using a JTextPane or a JEditorPane.

Here i am providing you with a simple example of how to provide JTextPane with a specified message to print and colour of that message.

you can change colours for any input text, such that it can display distinct colours for each word.

```
// This is in javax.swing.JTextPane;
JTextPane tPane = new JTextPane();

/* Method to put text in this textPane with colour of your choice
 * For this you need these classes.
 * import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
 * import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
 * import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
 * import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
 */

protected static void appendToPane(String msg, Color c,String f)
{
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);
    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, f);

    int len = tPane.getDocument().getLength();
    tPane.setCaretPosition(len);
    tPane.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
    tPane.replaceSelection(msg);
}
```

So if you call like this `appendToPane("HI", Color.RED, "Lucida Console")`
it will display HI in red with specified font.
and if you call say `appendToPane(" THERE", Color.BLACK, "TIMES NEW ROMAN")`
then THERE will be printed in black colour in the same place next to Hi.